# Providing a VMware VM - disk space allocation

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vmware, lvm

I'm not a VMware guru by any means so please be gentle, but I'm working on a product that will be readily available via a download of a VMware VM and I'm concerned about the size of the disk that my supplied VM has, as opposed to what would ultimately be required by the end user after using it for a period of time.

The only terminal access that the end user currently has automatically runs a script upon their login and allows them to assign IP details in order to attach the VM to their network; all other configurations are performed through a web based interface.

The VM is Ubuntu based and I have an LVM configured. Let's assume that the supplied VM contains a 5Gb drive (keeping the download itself to be as small as possible) and that the end user knows that they will - at some point - have to increase the disk space according to how they use the product. I'm considering the best way of allowing them to do that...

My thought is that if I update their login script that allows them to point to a new mounted drive (somewhere in their VM environment), that I will then use the various Ubuntu LVM commands to add the disk space to the existing LVM and so the product continues and everyone is happy.

I'm also going to be making the product available as a VirtualBox VM but AFAIK, to the product itself, it doesn't care what virtualization environment it's being operated in - at least, Ubuntu's LVM wouldn't ...

So, am I tackling this the right way?

Answer (score 0):

Some file systems allow live resizing, particularly if you just want to expand the size of the partition.

You could add the sizes of all existing partitions and if it is significantly smaller then execute a resize command.

You could also ask the user to add a virtual 2nd hard drive.  You could do LVM or you could just do mount points.  The "/var" folder and "/home" folders are usually the ones that change the most.  If you mapped those to different partitions on the 2nd hard drive you wouldn't need a lot of free space in your VM.

If you have a program that stores data elsewhere you can usually move the files either by changing the configuration files or use hard,soft, or etc links.

Answer (score 0):

> The VM is Ubuntu based and I have an LVM configured. Let's assume that the supplied VM contains a 5Gb drive (keeping the download itself to be as small as possible)

You could create the VM using a sparse virtual disk that has a capacity much larger than 5 GB.  When you're ready to distribute your VM, you then should use VMware Tools to wipe free space and compact the virtual disk so that it only consumes as much space as actually used:

```
vmware-toolbox-cmd disk list
```

to see a list of file system locations and then:

```
vmware-toolbox-cmd disk shrink LOCATION
```

for each of the listed locations.